# Show message from backend

Tags: plugin-development, customization, notices

I need to show messages on wordpress page editor, when a page is updated. I know there is a `admin_notice` hook to show messages. I have a `save_post_page` perfectly working on my code, but I need to know how to connect both of them and I don't know why?

Any help would be appreciate,

Best regards,

Ismael

Comment: Can you post some code (save post page) to see how you can add the `admin_notices` action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when a post is saved, there's a redirect back to the edit post page and the admin_notices action never runs. This means that any admin notice you put on any of the save post actions (save_post, transition_post_status, etc.) will be thrown away (since they're not persistent) during that redirect.

The workaround is to save a state (user settings/user meta, post meta, transients, options) which would signal that an admin notice should be shown, and look for that state on the next request.

```
add_action( 'save_post', function( $post ) {
    // some checks here
    update_user_option( get_current_user_id(), '_my_show_notice', true );
});

add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {
    if ( get_user_option( '_my_show_notice' ) ) {
        delete_user_option( get_current_user_id(), '_my_show_notice' );
        echo '<div class="notice notice-success"><p>Some notice</p></div>';
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!